# Unable to hit breakpoint in VS Code with Angular 13

Tags: angular, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Below is my `launch.js`

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "pwa-chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:4200",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

In `launch.js`, I have tried changing webRoot to `"webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src"`, it didn't have an impact.

My App is up and running with `ng serve`, yet when I hit `F5` to start the debug mode, none of the breakpoints are hit and they are all `unbound/greyed out`.

Below is my `angular.js` in case anyone needs it.

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "angular-u-project-one": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/angular-u-project-one",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": false,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "angular-u-project-one:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "angular-u-project-one:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "angular-u-project-one:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "angular-u-project-one:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "angular-u-project-one:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }},
  "defaultProject": "angular-u-project-one"
}
```

Below is my folder structure:

[image]

What else can be done to make it work?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, updating from Angular 11 to 13, then i found some helping and did the following steps in my proyect:

1.- Edit the : angular.json  file.

Add the following lines (sourceMap and optimization) into respective section or environments, by example :

```
"configurations": {
    .......
    .......
    .......
   "dev" : {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "optimization": false,
    ..... // More code
   },
   "devlocal" : {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "optimization": false,
    ..... // More code
   }


}
```

2.- Restart your angular application.
3.- Put your break points in your component.
4.- Debug your application with chrome or visual studio code.

And that's it !!!

It works forme. :)
Greets !!!

Comment: I have the same issue. When I try to add `sourceMap` I get the hint that the property is not allowed.